# How to specify a fixed width for rdlc tablix?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have created an rdlc report with a tablix where the number of columns varies dynamically. Is there a way I can specify a fixed width for the tablix regardless of the number of columns it contains?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes there is property in properties window which will help you. And even if you have googled it  you would have found that out.

Comment: If you want table to be fixed width regardless of number of columns, I'm afraid, the only way is to manipulate reports xml at run-time to re-set each "visible" column width to new "calculated" value.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to select the column/tablix and then in properties window you can specify the width.

Valid unit designators are in, mm, cm, pt, and pc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it won't solve my problem as it'll fix the width of each column. But I want the column widths to be dynamically adjusted to fit the entire tablix width (if possible).

Comment: You wanted to fix the length of the tablix so same as table there is property for fixing the width of the tablix

Comment: @HariPrasad Please read question carefully OP was asking for setting the fix length of the `tablix` and you have given solution to fix the length of the `Column` .That is wrong.

Comment: My bad, read it wrong initially. As @CoderofCode mentioned we can set property to fix tablix width. Thanks  'Coder of Code' for highlighting.

Comment: @CoderofCode, Are you referring to the 'Width' property (under Size) of a Tablix? I'm afraid it doesn't make the tablix width fixed when I hide some columns, instead tablix width get reduced. According to my requirement if my tablix width is 10in and I have only one column, that column should occupy the whole tablix width (10in). If you were referring to some other property it would be great if you can name it. Thanks!

Comment: @Karnain, did you found any solution for this case?